# Copy Files from Internal Storage to external storage

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Im trying to use Adobe reader to read pdf files downloaded from the server the problem is When i store it in the internal storage Other application can't read the file. Now i Want to know how can i **Copy** this **file in the external storage(/sdcard/)** so it can be viewed by pdf viewers.

Due to security reason I'm storing the files in the Internal Storage and would delete the one in external storage afterwards.

**My question is How can i copy the file saved in the internal storage without using the raw or the assets to put in the inputstream.**

```
    InputStream myInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.p13);

        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("sample", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        // Close the streams
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        myInput.close();
```

Comment: See my answer. Hope it will help you. If not then let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

at which path you are storing the pdf file ?

See below one to get file from android Assets and copy it to the specific sdcard location.

I will first check for the pdf file whether it is already available at desire path or not.

```
 File file1 = new File("/sdcard/SampleProjectApp/WindsorONE_Mobile_Molding.pdf");
    File file2 = new File("/sdcard/SampleProjectApp/WindsorONE_Mobile_PK.pdf");
    File file3 = new File("/sdcard/SampleProjectApp/Alone.mp4");

    if(!((file1.exists())) || !((file2.exists())) || !((file3.exists()))) {
        ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
        files.add("WindsorONE_Mobile_Molding.pdf");         
        files.add("WindsorONE_Mobile_PK.pdf"); 
        files.add("Alone.mp4");
        new myAsyncTask().execute(files);
    }
```

Now, if the file is not present at that position then it will execute the myAsyncTask to copy file from assets to the SdCard.

```
 // AsyncTass for the Progress Dialog and to do Background Process
private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, Void> {         
    ArrayList<String> files;         
    ProgressDialog dialog;         
    @Override         
    protected void onPreExecute() {             
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ListSample.this, "W1 SALES (beta)", "Loading...");         
    }         
    @Override         
    protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params) {              
        files = params[0];             
        for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {                 
            copyFileFromAssetsToSDCard(files.get(i));                
        }             return null;         
    }         
    @Override         
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {             
        dialog.dismiss();         
    }      
} 



 // Function to copy file from Assets to the SDCard
public void copyFileFromAssetsToSDCard(String fileFromAssets){
    AssetManager is = this.getAssets();
    InputStream fis;
    try {

        fis = is.open(fileFromAssets);
        FileOutputStream fos;
        if (!APP_FILE_PATH.exists()) {
            APP_FILE_PATH.mkdirs();
        }
        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/SampleProjectApp", fileFromAssets));
        byte[] b = new byte[8];
        int i;
        while ((i = fis.read(b)) != -1) {
            fos.write(b, 0, i);
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        fis.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Updated**

For your part:

replace
 **SampleProjectApp/WindsorONE_Mobile_Molding.pdf**

with

**Android/data/com.project.projectname/cache/YOUR_PDF_FILE.pdf**

Hope it make sense.

**Updated 2**

Below code is copy file from one path to another path. You simply have to pass the path of the file where it is exist and the path where it has to be copy.

Code:

```
public static boolean copyFile(String from, String to) {
try {
    int bytesum = 0;
    int byteread = 0;
    File oldfile = new File(from);
    if (oldfile.exists()) {
        InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(from);
        FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(to);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1444];
        while ((byteread = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            bytesum += byteread;
            fs.write(buffer, 0, byteread);
        }
        inStream.close();
        fs.close();
    }
    return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Im trying to store the pdf file in sdcard/Android/data/com.project.projectname/cache
im trying to store it in cache.

Comment: I have a question for the _copyFileFromAssetsToSDCard_ function as i'm new to android. Is the AssetManager getting the files from your app's package **res/raw** or android Internal storage **data/data/com.myproject.projectname/files/** 
Im having a _FileNotFoundException:myfile.pdf_ for this method

Comment: @GerjoBronosa: My friend you have to put the file in assets folder. AssetManager will not get file from the res/raw.

Comment: OK. but my problem is about copying files saved in the internal storage(data/data/com.example.project/files/file.pdf) not writing files from my assets or raw.

Comment: OK You just have to write code to get file from your desire path. Please wait till i update the answer.

Comment: @GerjoBronosa: Welcome anytime.  Enjoy Coding... :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method

```
boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

if(isSDPresent)
{
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
      in = //Place your file in the inputstream
      out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + filename);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int read;
      while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
      }
      in.close();
      in = null;
      out.flush();
      out.close();
      out = null;
}
else
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SD Card not present", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I'm getting a FileNotFoundException (Read-only file system). I'll add my codes on how i write the files in the internal storage too..

Comment: Im getting the file from the internal storage data/data/packagename/files/myfile.pdf

Comment: Use like this then `InputStream in = new FileInputStream("data/data/packagename/files/myfile.pdf")` or `InputStream in = new FileInputStream(Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/files/myfile.pdf")`

Comment: Im still getting a FileNotFoundException but now its No such File or directory. I dont think this is the way to access the internal directory **Environment.getDataDirectory()**

Comment: Did you use the DDMS perspective in eclipse to check if that file exists or not (Connect to the adb and use chmod 777 to view the internal files) ??

Comment: the file is at the directory with a **-rw-rw-----** permission