# include data file in creating apk package

Tags: android

```
 I am creating an app and use Ratio.xml as database. I added this file manually in external storage in a folder and my app is working.
```

I want to include this file in my apk package and install this file in any of the folder in the device and not in external storage . I added this file in asset folder but it is read only, I can't modify and save in this file. Please tell me where to put this file in my project and create package.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file from the assets and write the same file to external storage. Then you can modify and edit the file in external storage.
Try this link: [Copy Files from Internal Storage to external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247657/copy-files-from-internal-storage-to-external-storage)

Comment: I don't want to copy to sdcard because if there is no sdcard present then cant run the program.

Comment: Externalstorage doesn't mean sd card.

Comment: This can be a removable storage media (such as an SD card) or an internal (non-removable) storage. For further information check this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: thanks for the reply. I want to know where to put this file in my project for creating apk package, so this will be installed in the external storage.